# De .NET para Java, quais tecnologias ou frameworks utilizar?

Tags: java, asp.net

Atualmente tenho uma infraestrutura de trabalho baseada em .NET com Angular JS e surgiu uma possibilidade de um novo projeto utilizando Java.

Com .NET eu utilizo as seguintes tecnologias:

*ASP.NET Identity* 
Utilizado para autenticação e autorização. Gerenciamento de usuários de acesso com roles.

*ASP.NET Web API* 
Uma camada REST que é consumida por um client HTML5 com Angular JS, com recursos de autenticação e autorização baseados em ASP.NET Identity.

*ASP.NET Web Pages* 
Como o client-side utiliza Angular JS, em vez de gerar templates usando .html (puro) que não permitiria usar nenhum pré-processamento server-side, optei por utilizar .cshtml (web pages) que possibilita fazer verificações como essa:

```
<div>
    @if (User.IsInRole("admin")) { 
        <a href="/api/emp/excluir/5">Excluir</a> 
    }
</div>
```

Ou seja, caso o usuário logado não tenha privilégio as informações, ou certos trechos do template, nunca serão enviadas ao navegador. Isso é necessário para aumentar a segurança.

Como o mundo Java possui uma imensidade de frameworks disponíveis para as mais diversas necessidades, quais tecnologias em Java poderiam ser utilizadas para conseguir manter uma arquitetura similar?

Answer (score 4):

Minha sugestão:
A partir da versão 2.5.0 o Framework Demoiselle facilita o uso de uma arquitetura bastante parecida com a que vc comentou. [Guia de referência](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.5.0-RC1/html/)

Se já trabalha com Apache-Maven, pode utilizar o arquétipo demoiselle-html-rest para gerar uma aplicação de exemplo.

[image: Imagem da seleção do arquétipo demoiselle]

Comment: obrigado pela dica, vou manter a pergunta em aberto pq ainda vou me decidir ...

Comment: ok. caso precise de ajuda para desenvolver a solução no framework que sugeri, use a tag demoiselle quando fizer as perguntas aqui no stackoverflow. A comunidade do projeto oferece também curso em formato ensino à distância (EAD) gratuitos e com tutoria através da plataforma moodle. https://moodle.ead.serpro.gov.br/blocks/course_catalog/guia_aluno.php?exibe=c&org=2&categoria=2220&url=

Answer (score 2):

**Autenticação & Autorização**

Você pode usar [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html) que tem especificação própia, porem, as configurações dele costuma mudar de fornecedor (implementador) para fornecedor. Se quiser sair do padrão, pode usar [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/), ele é mais fácil de usar, mais fácil de entender e mais flexível.

**View**

Você pode usar [JSP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) primitivos que atendem ao cenário que você citou, ou, se tiver que usar templates, pode usar o [Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) que facilita muito o trabalho (eu diria que é um JSP++)

**REST**

Você pode usar JAX-RS que é um padrão no java, temos como exemplo o [RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) da JBoss ou até mesmo o [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) (implementação de referência).

A vantagem de todas essas tecnologias, é que todas elas conseguem se integrar e já são bem aceitas no mercado.

Comment: obrigado pela dica, vou manter a pergunta em aberto por enqto, mas já me deu uma boa ideia de onde começar

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer um app nas tecnologias que você já tem domínio ? creio que angular + .net deva fazer um trabalho excelente, talvez mudar para angular + java sejá só mais do mesmo :o)